# Why am I getting "The component(s) below failed to render"?

Tags: wicket, wicket-1.5

When I add a ChildPanel to a page, I get an error that states:

```
org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: 
The component(s) below failed to render.
A common problem is that you have added a component in code 
but forgot to reference it in the markup 
(thus the component will never be rendered).

1. [Form [Component id = myForm]]
2. [DropDownChoice [Component id = referenceType]]
3. [TextField [Component id = referenceNumber]]
4. [CheckBox [Component id = referenceReqChk]]
5. [ [Component id = saveRefNumButton]]
6. [ [Component id = cancelRefNumButton]]

    at org.apache.wicket.Page.checkRendering(Page.java:693)
    at org.apache.wicket.Page.onAfterRender(Page.java:849)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.WebPage.onAfterRender(WebPage.java:213)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.afterRender(Component.java:950)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.render(Component.java:2298)
    at org.apache.wicket.Page.renderPage(Page.java:1041)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.
           WebPageRenderer.renderPage(WebPageRenderer.java:105)
```

I can clearly see the components in question are added in the markup in my AbstractParentPanel, which my ChildPanel extends.  The odd thing is, if I make the AbstractParentPanel a non-abstract class, I'm able to add that panel with no issues.

Why am I getting this error?

*NOTE: I have already found the answer to this question.  I'm adding it to SO to help others since I wasted more time than I should have for such a simple check.  If you got burned by this message and this answer helped you, consider voting up [this JIRA ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WICKET-4615)*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Always start with the obvious and make sure the `wicket:id(s)` are defined in your markup.  If you see the ID added in your markup, then chances are you have the following scenario:

- You are trying to render a Component that is a child of another Component. This means your trying to render a Page or a Panel that is a subclass of a another Page or Panel.

  - e.g. Within a Page you try to call `add(new ChildPanel("myChildPanel"));`
- The Component you are extending has defined and add Components with it's own markup

  - e.g. Within `AbstractParentPanel` you call `add(new Label("myCommonLabel"));`
- The markup in the child Component failed to included some required Wicket XHTML

  - e.g. Within `ChildPanel.html`, you forgot to add `<wicket:extend>` tags or maybe even `<wicket:panel>` tags, or you have them not containing the components in question.

Comment: Make sure the string `wicket:id` isn't misspelled either. I spent half an hour once tracking down every other possibility, then noticed that I had `wicker:id` in the markup. :)

Comment: @biziclop :-)  The QWickie plugin helps me avoid that, but I feel your pain.

Comment: I am encountering this frequently when overriding a method creating a component, e.g. `AbstractTab.getPanel(String panelId)` but do not (or not correctly) use the panelId argument for constructing my component, e.g. `return MyPanel("panelId");` instead of `return MyPanel(panelId);` (Note the quotes around panelId.)

Comment: Another common personal gotcha of mine is writing `<div class="myComponentId"></div>` instead of `<div wicket:id="myComponentId"></div>`. This one hurts most! ;-)

Comment: Why do my fingers always type wicked ?

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that you are setting a Wicket component's `wicket:id` instead of the `id`! This one gets me all the time.

Comment: Yeah, I originated Wicket a dozen years ago and this issue got me YESTERDAY. I kindof wish we had called it something else, although it does make reasonable sense too. Hindsight is 20/20.

Answer (score 4):

Another possibility is that your page has not any markup. This can accidently happen if the name of your java class does not match the name of your html. I struggled recently with a case-sensitiv situation here.

Comment: Martin isn't asking a question.  He's simply stating that another cause for the "The component(s) below failed to render." error is if you have a case mismatch on your file.  It's a valid point.  It doesn't address the issue I was having, but it might help someone else.